# Как вернуть переменную из функции javascript?

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
friends = Object();

VK.api("friends.get", {
    fields: "uid"
}, function (data) {
    var count = data.response.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < friendCount; i++) {
        friends[data.response[i].uid] = data.response[i].uid; // << Как эту переменную записать в ранее созданную переменную или обратиться к ней?!!
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запустить далее по цепочке событий, а именно так как вы хотите - никак, вернее можно, но большого смысла в этом нет т.к. вам все-равно нужно передавать callback.

Событийно-ориентированное программирование  подразумевает использование схемы вида: `event -> handler`, естественно такого рода последовательность может продолжатся, т.е.: `event->handler->event->handler...`, это небольшое пояснение, для того что-бы вы понимали почему так нельзя.

Пожалуй продолжу мысль - на самом деле, если быть точным - это можно реализовать синхронным ajax запросом, но это каменный век , более того, с т.з. javascript'a является, мягко говоря, плохим тоном (хотя не скрою, иногда это удобно и нужно, но это бывает довольно редко и это не тот случай).

Грубо говоря - вы можете использовать объект friends например для кэширования информации( если объект пуст - делаем запрос, после получения результата - пишем в переменную (которую желательно не делать глобальной), передаем обработчику результат. Теперь, при следующем запросе, нет необходимости делать запрос, можно сразу-же передавать ранее полученный результат ), но это не освобождает вас от необходимости использовать событийно ориентированную модель.

В самом простом ее понимании на абстрактном примере JS псевдокода:

```
// сначало вариант, как говорится, в лоб
var databaseResult = someDatabase.getAllFrom('someCollectionStorage');
// с применением собитийно-ориентированной модели
someDatabase.getAllFrom('someCollectionStorage', function( res ) {
   // здесь мы можем использовать результат путем обращения
   // к переменной res
});
```

Принципиальное различие обеих подходов, в первую очередь, заключается в том, что у нас, во втором случае, нет прямой необходимости блокировать главный поток до того, как отработает выборка из нашей абстрактной базы-данных, либо, например, не произойдет ошибка( так-же как и чтение файла, ajax запрос и т.д. и т.п. ). Мы можем заниматься другими вещами, обрабатывать другие события и продолжить работу над результатом выборки лишь тогда, когда он будет готов. Собственно это и есть javascript way.

В вашем случае я бы сделал как-то так:

```
var getFriends = (function() {
 var friends;
 return function( callback ) {
  if( friends === undefined ) {
   VK.api("friends.get", {fields:"uid"}, function(data) {
     var count = data.response.length;
     for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      friends[data.response[i].uid] = data.response[i].uid;
     }
     callback( friends );
   });
  }
  else {
   callback( friends );
  }
 }
})();
```

На самом деле, при написании JavaScript кода - нельзя мыслить так-же как, например, при написании PHP кода. Вернее можно, но не нужно =)

PS: Если ув. читателю ответа попалась неверно, либо не до конца, изложенная мысль - просьба ткнуть носом, устал за сегодня, писал  на полном "автомате"

Comment: Кстати - у вас проблема в коде:

    var count = data.response.length;
       for (var i = 0; i < friendCount; i++)
       // как я понимаю сравнение должно иметь вид
       // i < count