# Где ошибка в коде js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Написал код:

```
var whil = n3.children('.trade_item'); 
var all = 0; var one = [], two = [];

for(var i = 0; i < whil.size(); i++) {
    $('.primary:last', data).children('.tradeoffer_item_list').children('.trade_item').each(function(i){
        one.push($(this).attr("data-economy-item").split('/')[2]);
        two.push($(this).attr("data-economy-item").split('/')[3]);
    });

    var ad = Price("http://steamcommunity.com/economy/itemhover/730/2/" + one[i] + "?o=" + two[i]);

    all += ad;                  
}

$('#w').html(all);
```

Сразу скажу что функция `Price` - рабочая. Она возвращает просто цифру.

Но почему-то `$('#w').html(all);` возвращает код функции `Price` (именно js код ф-и), по этому - код ф-и `Price`:

```
function Price(url) {

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.send();

    return xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
        {
            if (xhr.responseText) 
            {
                var data = xhr.responseText;

                    var pattern = /"market_hash_name":"(.*?)"/;

                    var match = data.match(pattern);

                    var name = match[1];

                    //$('#wrapper').html('name = ' + encodeURIComponent(name));

                if (name) {
                    var url2 = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=5&appid=730&market_hash_name=' + encodeURIComponent(name);                 

                    $.get(url2, function(data){

                        var pattern = /"lowest_price":"(.*?)"/;

                        var match = data.match(pattern);

                        var name = match[1].split('p')[0];

                        //$('#w').html(name);

                    }, "html");

                }   

            }

        } 
      return name;
    }

}
```

Скрин вывода:

[image: скрин]

Что я не так сделал и как исправить ?

Так же [Код сайта](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hMJkwjyz3E3LtcfmSKLFNApAxxYIPNmD9cbeZOF0mxg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Price не возвращает число, он возвращает объект запроса.

Comment: А как мне вернуть именно переменную name ? Там же стоит `return name;`

Comment: Зачем вы задали новый вопрос вместо того, чтобы изменить предыдущий?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательнее на вот эту строчку:

```
return xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
```

В ней вы возвращаете из функции Price другую функцию.

Что же до того, как сделать правильно - на этом сайте отвечали на такой вопрос уже много раз. Вот что я нашел:

[Как вернуть значение из вложенной функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

[Как вернуть переменную из функции javascript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/112287/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-javascript)

[Вернуть $.ajax data в return функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/226606/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-ajax-data-%D0%B2-return-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Answer (score 3):

У вас проблема в том, что `XMLHttpRequest` работает асинхронно, так что результат обработать можно только внутри функции которая будет "привязана" к событию окончания загрузки данных:

```
var all = 0; // и прочее

// обработчик, вызовется по окончани запроса
function reqListener () {
    var htmlResp = this.responseText; // содержимое которое вернул запрос
    // здесь обработка как у вас в price
    all += ad;
    $('#w').html(all);
}

var url = "http://steamcommunity.com/economy/itemhover/730/2/" + one[i] + "?o=" + two[i];
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener); // установили обработчик на окончание загрузки данных
oReq.open("POST", url, true);
oReq.send();
```

Кстати раз уж вы используете jQuery вам проще использовать уже существующую [обертку для ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) с промисами:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ваш урл',
    method: 'POST'
}).done(function(data){
    // в 'data' содержимое ответа на запрос
    // ваш код обработки
});
```