# $http не срабатывает внутри фабрики Angular

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день.

Решил вынести функционал получения данных в отдельную фабрику, но по непонятной мне причине $http не отрабатывает вообще.

Фабрика:

```
angular
.module('quApp')
.factory('ingredientFactory', function($http){

    return {
    getIngrs : function(){
        var res = {};
        $http.get('/ingredient')
            .then(function(data) {
                res = data;
            },
            function(err) {
                res = err;
            });
        return res;
       }
    };
});
```

При вызове фабрика возвращает пустой res.
Где я напортачил?

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно выразился товарищ Mayorov - проблема в асинхронности.
В данном случае можно использовать промисы:

```
/* global angular */

angular.module('quApp', []).factory('ingredientFactory',
function($http, $q){

    return {
        getIngrs : getIngrsFn
    };

    function getIngrsFn(){
        var defer=$q.defer();

        $http({method: 'GET', url: '/ingredient'})
        .success(function(data) {
            defer.resolve(data);
        }).error(function(err) {
            defer.reject(err);
        });

        return defer.promise;
    };

});
```

Использование в контроллере:

```
ingredientFactory.getIngrs().then(
    function(data){Удачка;},
    function(error){Печалька;}
);
```

[Документация по $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Хабр раз - 189084 - Promise-ы в AngularJS;

Хабр два - 221111 - Правильное использование promise в angular.js

(оказывается, с низкой репутацией, нельзя добавить больше одной ссылки =\ );

P.S.: И да, лично по моему скромному мнению, всё выше перечисленное пойдет для общего развития, а для конкретной ситуации как-то бессмысленно. Если бы в фабрике выполнялась какая-то пост обработка данных, то да, а так мы просто меняем $http на $q.

Answer (score 0):

И опять попытка синхронного возврата значения из асинхронного кода... Вот вам ссылки, которые я нашел. Там не про angular, а про jquery - но ошибка та же самая.

[Как вернуть значение из вложенной функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

[Как вернуть переменную из функции javascript?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/112287/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-javascript)

[Вернуть $.ajax data в return функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/226606/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-ajax-data-%D0%B2-return-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0):

```
    gameServices.factory('Content', ['$http',
        function($http) {
            var service = function() {
                this.items = [];          
            };
        service.prototype.nextPage = function(callback) {
    //Тут загрузка контента
 $http.get(url).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                this.items = data;
                if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback();
                }
            }.bind(this)).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
        }
            return service;
        }
    ]);
```